# How to handle class, activity design, in Android game

Tags: android

I am creating a game similar to Pokemon and right now I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle my battle.

I have created a monster class which when instanced contains a particular monster's name, health, stats, etc.  I will have two monsters fighting each other with the player able to select a move (will likely be a class as well with damage, info, and type stats) to attack the opponent with.

Would I be best served to make the Moves class an activity so that I can use methods to attack and calculate damage? Or should I create a battle activity which I send the monsters pertinent stats and have it deal with changing the health and printing out the text explaining what happened?  This way, my monster and moves class only holds the information and doesn't use any methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design perspective, your second thought is more on cue.

The basic idea that you have is that each object (Monster, in this case) will have public functions available to get what moves are available, current stats, etc.

Thus the Battle Activity will expect to have one or more Monster objects per team, rules defined as to what makes the battle win, handle which monster goes first, etc.

Thus if a monster takes damage and we need to save that, you can make a function in the Monster class such as:

```
public void takeDamage(double damage) {
 this.hp -= damage;
 //Handle status updates if hp <= 0

 //Automatically save the monster's state, to prevent cheating by quitting before battle is over!
 this.saveMonsterState();
}
```

And this would be called from the Battle activity whenever one monster hits another.  Hope that helps!